# Easier way to calculate Nullity of triple composition of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$T:R^3\to R^3$

$T(x,y,z)=(x+3y+2z,3x+4y+z,2x+y-z)$

I want to find the dimension of the Null Space of $T^3$

Here Nullity of $T$ is not $0$, so I can't say anything directly about the nullity of $T^3$

Normally for the nullity of T, I would form the matrix of transformation by take the image of the standard basis of $R^3$, then row reduce to calculate the rank and use the dimension theorem.

But doing the same for $T^3$ is turning out to be hefty task and I am looking for a easier way.

Comment: Are you calculating the matrix $T^3$ or trying to calculate the function $T^3$ when you say it is a "hefty task"?

Comment: @AnthonyTer I am first calculating the image of standard basis of $R^3$ under $T^3$, then form the matrix of transformation of $T^3$ and from there I would calculate the rank of this matrix and use dimension theorem

Comment: Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Just form the matrix of transformation $T$ first then cube it, find nullity of that matrix.